# Finite State Machine with limited operations

Tags: finite-automata

I have to implement a state machine in some special hardware which has a lot of limitations. This hardware can be understood as a box that gets events as inputs and could output events.

The state machine is very small 3-4 states that are al connected as a ring 0->1->2->3->0 plus some states have loops with themselves. Thus the new state will always be either the same or current + 1 mod N.

A state change can be triggered by two things:

1. A given event can trigger a state change.
2. There is a global counter that increases every time an event arrives. If the counter reaches certain value (depending on the current state) that can trigger a state change.

The biggest problem is that every time an event arrives at the box I can only do the following:

1. Read the counter value, increase it by one and save it in memory again.
2. Read the current state and I have to compute instantaneously the next state and save it. Variables can not be accesses twice. Meaning that I can not read it, do a complex operation and then write the new state down. The only thing I am allowed to do is: I can define 2 simple boolean expressions of the form (+- current_state +/- variable (==, !=, >, >=,...) Constant. The output of those 2 bolean expressions can be used to decide how the state is updated. However the only thing you can do is: update the state in way A (i.e state+1), update state in way B (i.e state -1) and not modify it.

For example:

if expression1:
    state= state+1
if expresion2 and not expresion1:
    state= state-1

if not expresion1 and not expresion2:
   state = state.

Basically the hardware circuit that is executed is comprised of the following:

- 2 comparison units that can produce 2 bolean outputs (as explained above).
- 2 ALUS that can perform fixed operations if enabled using the result of the comparisons.
- The result of the ALU can be written back to memory, (this is our state).
- The updated state can be outputted from the box.

I know it might be a bit confusing, but I did not find a better way to explain the hardware using a small text. I can clarify things.

**Question:**

Do you think there is a way to implement a small state machine given those constrains?

Comment: I don't follow your explanation of exactly which operations you can perform. What is a "variable"? How does it obtain a value?

Comment: It seems straightforward.  Have two variables in memory: one to hold the current state of the state machine, and one to hold the counter.   Each time an event arrives, read the current state and the counter and the event type and use that to decide the value of the next state.

Comment: There is no in memory this is an algorithm that runs in hardware. The current state is saved in this hardware structure, at the time you read it, you have 2 if conditions and 2 possible ways of updating the state. I is not straightforward.